# Map JSON response that has brackets with RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I'm doing a GET request with RESTKit, and I need sone help mapping the JSON response.
Here is the response that I need to map:

```
{"limit_hit":false,"providers":
    [{"id":876553,
    "name":"Cooper, Bradley N, DDS",
    "specialty_groups":["Other Provider"],
    "tags":[],
    "has_comments":false,
    "number_of_comments":0,
    "locations":
        [{"address":"1234 Rifle Range Road, El Cerrito, CA, 94530",
        "providers_at_address_count":1,
        "client_product_count":0,
        "non_client_product_count":2,
        "address_lines":["1234 Rifle Range Road, El Cerrito, CA, 94530"],
        "address_id":234578,
        "specialty_groups":
            [{"specialty_group":"Other Provider"}],
        "provider_types":
            [{"provider_type":"Other Provider"}]},

        {"address":"7501 Mission Rd, Shawnee Mission, KS, 66208",
        "providers_at_address_count":2,
        "client_product_count":0,
        "non_client_product_count":2,
        "address_lines":["7654 Main S, El Cerrito, CA, 94530"],
        "address_id":654432,
        "specialty_groups":
            [{"specialty_group":"Other Provider"}],
        "provider_types":
            [{"provider_type":"Other Provider"}]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to be able to map both addresses, but I don't know how. All I'm able to do currently is map the id, name, has_comments, and number_of_comments (I'm using the keypath of "providers").
Here is my current mapping provider:

```
+ (RKMapping *)searchMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ProviderSearch class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id": @"doctorID",
     @"name": @"name",
     }];
    return mapping;
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Create another method to return the mapping for `locations` and then associate that mapping to this original one. Like this:

```
// ProviderLocation.m
+ (RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ProviderLocation class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"address": @"address",
     ...
     }];
    return mapping;
}
```

Relationship:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)searchMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ProviderSearch class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id": @"doctorID",
     @"name": @"name",
     }];

    RKObjectMapping *locationsMapping = [ProviderLocation objectMapping];
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:
        [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"locations" toKeyPath:@"locations" withMapping:locationsMapping]];

    return mapping;
}
```

Just remember to create a NSArray property in `ProviderLocation.h` named `locations`.

Comment: I assume by ProviderLocation you mean ProviderSearch, as I don't have a ProviderLocation class.

Comment: Actually not. I was assuming you are using MVC, so as you have ProvideSearch as a model to be mapped, you also have another model to map the address and then create the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

i've never used RKObjectMapping before but the "locations" you have there are an array of dictionary objects. so you would need an

```
NSArray loc = [myJson objectForKey:@"locations"];
for(NSDictionary *dict in loc){
    //here each dict obj will have your "address",  "providers_at_address_count" and etc... so if you want to access any of them you can call...
    NSString *addr = [dict objectForKey:@"address"];
 }
```

now somehow convert that to what you are doing with RXObjectMapping and you are golden =P